# Generate java classes from dynamic xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am able to generate java class from xsd file by using JAX-B but am not able to get valid java class in case my xsd contains duplicate elements name . Please let us know how to generate my java class without any errors.

My xsd file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SearchResults">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ResultCode"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UserTrackId"/>
        <xs:element name="BusDetails">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Item1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ScheduleId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="StationId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="BusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BusName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="TransportId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TransportName"/>
                    <xs:element name="FareDetails">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Item1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="SeatTypeId"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatTypeName"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Fare"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:float" name="ServiceTax"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="CoachTypeId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DepartureTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ArrivalTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatsAvailable"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="StatusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="StatusDesc"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Item2">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ScheduleId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="StationId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="BusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BusName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="TransportId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TransportName"/>
                    <xs:element name="FareDetails">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Item1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="SeatTypeId"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatTypeName"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="Fare"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="ServiceTax"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Item2">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="SeatTypeId"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatTypeName"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="Fare"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="ServiceTax"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="CoachTypeId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DepartureTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ArrivalTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatsAvailable"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="StatusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="StatusDesc"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Item3">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ScheduleId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="StationId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BusName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="TransportId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TransportName"/>
                    <xs:element name="FareDetails">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Item1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="SeatTypeId"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatTypeName"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="Fare"/>
                                <xs:element type="xs:double" name="ServiceTax"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="CoachTypeId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DepartureTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ArrivalTime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SeatsAvailable"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="StatusId"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="StatusDesc"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: In the above xsd Item1 and Item2 are duplicate element names. Kindly help me out .....

Comment: How you are generating the classes from XSD?

Comment: @Balu Is it possible to see the error? can you post it here.

Comment: What a terrible schema design! Any thoughts of refactoring the schema and create a common type that can be reused by each item?

Comment: @Garry  i am generating java classes from jax-b plugin from eclipse

Comment: can you try using command line as suggested below in answer?

Comment: Were you able to generate? Please let us know if you are still facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command line like below, try to add "-nv" option to skip strict validation

```
xjc -d src -p -nv com.gsdev.jaxb.beans employee.xsd
```

"-nv" => By default, the XJC binding compiler performs strict validation of the source schema before processing it. Use this option to disable strict schema validation. This does not mean that the binding compiler will not perform any validation, it simply means that it will perform less-strict validation